# Android Listview OnItemClickListener sometimes not working

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a small Android APP with a listview in it. Sometimes the listview does not react on my inputs. I can see that I touched on one item (it changes the color as I touched it), but the program does nothing.
This is my XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRowLable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewRowLable"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRemainingTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewRowLable"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the listner:

```
 .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
```

Could someone give me a hint why it is not always working?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on your `RelativeLayout`
Also go through this tutorials:
[Listview tips and tricks](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/)

Comment: Problem is still there. 2 out of 10 touches are not noticed by the app. I have no idea why.

Comment: I have the same problem and didn't figure it out. Did you found the root causing this behaviour? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Than I looked at the Android source and found the reason.

In the click handling, there is the following line

```
if (mDataChanged) return;
```

So the click is discarded, when the internal list data has changed.

I have updated the list very often. Reducing the update interval solved the problem nearly (after the change, only 1 of 100 clicks was not recognized)